# SOQL not returning data when there is a record in DB

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, soql

The following code is called from Opportunity trigger. So the flow is

1. From opportunity trigger call MyTwiMLController.processoutboundCall()
2. After the callout it calls the VF page "TwiMLPage" by passing the OppId as parameter in the url
3. Then it goes back to controller method getTwiml()

The problem that I am facing is it is not returning any data in the SOQL even if the record exist from getTwiML method. What I am missing here to understand?

***Opportunity Trigger***

```
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if(opp.Status__c == 'QW-RV'){
            TwilioConnectorController twiMLCon = new TwilioConnectorController();
            twiMLCon.processoutboundCall(opp.Id);
         }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public with sharing class TwilioConnectorController {
    public User rep {get; set;}
    public String callerName {get; set;}
    public List<Opportunity> oppLst{get;set;}


    public String processoutboundCall(String oppId){
        String toPhNum = [select Contact.MobilePhone FROM OpportunityContactRole
                            WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId AND Role='Primary Contact'].Contact.MobilePhone;
        if(String.isNotEmpty(toPhNum)){
            String formattedtoNum = toPhNum.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');
            String url = 'http://pk-silo.cs29.force.com/TwiMLPage?oppId='+oppId;   //parameter passed to the URL
            Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
                    'To'   => formattedtoNum,
                    'From' => '+15629916679',
                    'Url' =>    url
            };
            DoCallout(params);
        }
        else{
            Error_Log__c logCallError = new Error_Log__c(Type__c='Twilio Outbound',
                                            Error_Message__c='No valid primary contact Mobile Number.'+' '+'OppId:'+oppId);
            Insert logCallError;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    private static void DoCallout(Map<String, String> params){
        TwilioConfig__c tw = TwilioConfig__c.getInstance('00eF00000013nqJ');
        String account = tw.AccountSid__c;
        String token   = tw.AuthToken__c;
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);
        TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
        system.debug('TwilioCAL LOG' + call);
    }

    public String getTwiml() {
        String oppId1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
        System.debug('getTwiml oppId value'+oppId1);
     /*   String toPhNum1 = [select Contact.MobilePhone FROM OpportunityContactRole
        WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId1 AND Role='Primary Contact'].Contact.MobilePhone;
        System.debug('phonenum from Twiml'+toPhNum1);*/
        oppLst = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: oppId1 ]);
        String acntName = [SELECT Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id=: oppId1].Account.Name;
        System.debug('Opp list value is'+acntName);
        return null;
    }

}
```

**VF Page****

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<apex:page sideBar="false"  showHeader="false" action="{!getTwiml}" controller="TwilioConnectorController" contentType="application/xml">
    <Response>
        <Say>You will be connected to the merchant</Say>
        <!--Dial>
            <Number>516-333-7889</Number>
        </Dial-->
    </Response>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I found the issue. Using system.currentPagereference.getparameters from site page url is returning ID value as (006m0000007zWu8AAE) with parantheiss. I have to remove those special characters and was able to achieve the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `with sharing` in the apex controller so it obeys the principle where the record is shared to the user.

So, if you login with the user and try to access the opportunity from the URL and check if that user has access to the Opportunity record.

It seems user doesn't have access to the Opportunity record and hence it is not returning any data in the SOQL.

**Update based on comments**

Site page url is sending OpportunityId which is having parenthesis and needs to be removed before putting that in SOQL.

Comment: The opportunity is assigned to me(Sys admin) and I tried to change the class as "without" sharing and even in that case it didn't work. And also I moved the code from apex trigger to Process builder and it didn't worked either.

Comment: can you take the OpportunityId and put that into the URL and check if that record is showing

Comment: The only difference here is SOQL is execute as site user. I verified the public access setting for site user and everything seems to fine. If I execute SOQL Account, Lead objects it is returning data but only on Opportunity it is returning null. Does site user has access to Opportunity data?

Comment: go to the user's profile check the access, I need to look into that

Comment: If I hardcode Id value it is returning data. For example oppLst = [SELECT Name,Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE
                    Id= '06m0000007zWu8'. But If I use variable it doesn't return any data. For example the following doesn't work, oppLst = [SELECT Name,Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE
                    Id=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId')];

Comment: Put debug on `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId')` and also trim the value before putting that in SOQL

Comment: As you can see from the debug screenshot in my post I have already verified value coming through currentPage() parameters. Also what do you mean by trim?

Comment: oppLst = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:oppId1]; change this line

Comment: Sorry @Santanu. I couldn't follow you. Could you please explain?

Comment: I think you meant to say this which didn't made any difference. oppCallerId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('oppId');
        oppCallerId = oppCallerId.trim();

Comment: I found the issue. Using system.currentPagereference.getparameters from site page url is returning ID value as (006m0000007zWu8AAE) with parantheiss. I have remove those special characters and was able to achieve the result.

Comment: nice to hear that, Can you accept my answer so that others may find that useful. I have updated my answer